# Simple jquery slideshow - make order random

Tags: jquery

I'm extremely novice with jquery. Barely know a thing.

On my new minimalist site i am using a very simple jquery slideshow, and I love how it works. But one thing it is missing is the ability to fire at random. Would anyone share with me what I would need to add to the code to make it do this?

You can see it on my site [www.twentyfivethree.com](http://www.twentyfivethree.com)

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(2250)
         .next('img').fadeIn()
         .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
      7000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: have you got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<div id="wrapper">
      <img src="dog.jpg">
      <img src="cat.jpg">
</div>


  $(document).ready(function(){
      var $imageArr = $('#wrapper img'),
      imageArrLength = $imageArr.length,
      randNum = Math.floor ( Math.random ( ) * imageArrLength + 1 );
      // show image that is nth child of image array
      $imageArr.eq(randNum-1).show();
}
```

Comment: I already have a jquery slideshow that i'm wanting to add random functionality to..

Comment: please take a look at the current markup I am using for my slideshow. And see where you would add the 'random' value in..            <script>
$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(2250)
         .next('img').fadeIn()
         .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
      7000);
});
</script>